# Can't scrape link from a web page

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

So I'm trying to get this link from this site https://www.gotriple.eu/documents?q=10.14746/pt.2016.26.8 with python:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llQkP.png)

but after rendering the site I only get placeholders instead of links:

`<div class="gt-search-result "><ul><li class="gt-search-result__item"><div class="gt-content-placeholder"><div class="gt-content-placeholder__item result-title-placeholder"></div><div class="gt-content-placeholder__item result-metadata-placeholder"></div><div class="gt-content-placeholder__item result-metadata-placeholder"></div><div class="gt-content-placeholder__item result-metadata-placeholder"></div><div class="gt-content-placeholder__item result-metadata-placeholder">`

that's my code:

```
    async def FromTriple(self, doi):
        asession = AsyncHTMLSession()
        url = 'https://www.gotriple.eu/documents?q=' + doi[16:] #Adding DOI without https://doi.org/

        website = await asession.get(url)
        await website.html.arender(sleep=3, keep_page=True)
        
        links = website.html.find('li a')

        return links
```

I tried extending sleep, but it doesn't make any difference. Selenium is the last resort, but I don't want to place path to a web browser in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that `website.html.arender` already invokes [a full web browser](https://requests.readthedocs.io/projects/requests-html/en/latest/#requests_html.HTML.render).

But if you don't want to use it, a good alternative is to imitate what the frontend code is doing. By looking at the Network tab of the browser's devtools, and looking for non-asset requests (i.e. ignoring js, svg, woff2, etc), we can see there's an API endpoint for searches:

> https://api.gotriple.eu/documents?q=10.14746/pt.2016.26.8&size=25&page=1&aggs=topic,size=99,sort=count,order=desc;in_language,size=99,sort=count,order=desc;type,size=99,sort=count,order=desc;provider,size=99,sort=count,order=desc;author,size=20,sort=count,order=desc;conditions_of_access,size=99,sort=count,order=desc;license,size=99,sort=count,order=desc;year,size=200,sort=item,order=desc;&fq=&from=undefined&to=undefined

Most of the query params seem to be default values that can be omitted, so we only keep `https://api.gotriple.eu/documents?q=10.14746/pt.2016.26.8`.

The server response is a JSON document with the search results. That's much nicer than HTML, since you only need `website.json()` to parse, and the data is easily accessible, and this one has a full [ontology](https://gotriple.eu/ontology/triple) in case you need clarification on the meaning of a field.

Each search result is a JSON object, and the document links are in fields named `main_entity_of_page`. For some reason the value is a list, so be prepared for having any number of "main entities".

```
import requests
doi = '10.14746/pt.2016.26.8'
response = requests.get(f'https://api.gotriple.eu/documents?q={doi}')
for result in response.json()['hydra:member']:
    for entity in result['main_entity_of_page']:
        print(entity)
        # https://bibliotekanauki.pl/articles/1391644
```